# How to change the contact icon shape in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

[image]

This icon in Outlook is currently showing square shaped. I would like to change it to a circle shape. How can I do this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this automatically happens when you add an image.

Comment: Okay because on a different laptop I have it is showing the icons has circles ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in ProPlus desktop version. The latest Office 365 Outlook provides circle contact images.